# Bing News Search API returns truncated name of news

Tags: api, search, bing, azure-cognitive-services

How to get full news name from API?

We are trying to get news using https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-cognitiveservices-newssearch module.
Making search request and receiving truncated name field in the response.

Please check response:

[image]

Comment: Have exactly the same problem. Did you eventually solve it?